# Sorting radgrid gridtemplatecolumns with changing or dynamic column value

Tags: sorting, telerik, expression, radgrid

Usually to sort columns in a `RadGrid` I use the `sortexpression` and `text` in `GridTemplateColumn`. But now its different; here I have a `RadGrid` with several columns, All of them are `GridTemplateColumns`. I have a collection binding the `RadGrid`.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn ItemStyle-BorderWidth="0" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
    HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" UniqueName="CustomerSupplierName" ShowSortIcon="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSupplierName" runat="server" />
        <%-- Text='<%# Eval("SupplierNameText")%>'/>--%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

This is one of those columns. Now in the databound function I populate the grid. I have a radiobutton list on my page completely away from this grid. Based on its selected index I change the value to be populated into this specific column (`UniqueName="CustomerSupplierName"`). Like this

In ItemDataBound:

```
If rblCustomersSuppliers.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    Dim lblSupplierName As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblSupplierName")
    lblSupplierName.Text = cont.SupplierNameText
Else
    Dim lblSupplierName As Label = e.Item.FindControl("lblSupplierName")
    lblSupplierName.Text = cont.CustomerOrganization
End If
```

So I either bind a suppliername or customerorganization based on selection. Now I need this column to be sortable. How do i do that? If you need more info, please ask. Thanks

EDIT:
Itemdatabound

```
 If TypeOf e.Item Is GridHeaderItem Then
 If rblCustomersSuppliers.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
       rgContractHistory.MasterTableView.GetColumn("CustomerName").Visible = False
            rgContractHistory.MasterTableView.GetColumn("SupplierName").Visible = True
 Else
   item("CustomerName").Text = "Customer"
            rgContractHistory.MasterTableView.GetColumn("CustomerName").Visible = True
            rgContractHistory.MasterTableView.GetColumn("SupplierName").Visible = False
  End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `UniqueName` attribute should not used in sorting as it is intended to be a unique identifier of the column; instead the `DataField` should define the column (from the database) to sort by.

So the event handlers you want to consider looking at is the `DataBinding` or, if using Advanced Data Binding, the `NeedDataSource`. From here it might be possible to change the `DataField` assigned to the column.

Example code for getting the column:

```
Dim columnToChange As GridTemplateColumn = CType(grdUsers.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueNameSafe("CustomerSupplierName"), GridTemplateColumn)
If rblCustomersSuppliers.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    columnToChange.DataField = "SupplierNameText"
Else
    columnToChange.DataField = "CustomerOrganization"
End If
```

An alternative method would be to have two separate columns, hiding and showing them depending on the currently selected `RadioButton`, this would require a reasonable amount of code changing as you would need to clear the filter text of the column being hidden, and probably move it into the column being shown. (Sorry but I believe it would be quite involved and I don't really have time to go into an example)

None of the above code has been tested/syntax checked but hopefully will give you reasonable pointers as to where to look next.

Comment: Thanks. I took the alternative idea you suggested. So, a column is shown and other is hidden based on the radio button selection. But still they are not sortable. I have different unique names for both columns. But for the sortexpression i gave the datafield from database. What is going wrong?See my edited question

Comment: Whenever I'm doing filtering I use something along the lines of the following: `<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SupplierNameText" UniqueName="SupplierName" HeaderText="Supplier Name" AllowFiltering="true" AllowSorting="true" FilterControlWidth="100%" />` I'd use the `Display` attribute rather than `Visible` as when `Visible` is set to false the field will not be populated. the `DataField` attribute should contain the column name and you shouldn't need to populate the `SortExpression` as this should work automatically to match the assigned `DataField`